# Java:HashMap<String,String> storing same value as key and value.?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, hashmap, key-value

I am getting this strange output in `HashMap`.

I have two `ArrayList<String>` one containing the key and another containing value.

My `HashMap<String,String>` will store only string as key and value pair. But key itself is getting stored in value. I have checked my value arraylist, it's printing the value. But during putting it's setting it as key itself.

Code snippet is:

```
public HashMap<String,String> getLstBarring()
    {
        ArrayList<String> temparrLst=setPreParameters(fetchPreDetails, 1);
        System.out.println("KEY"    +  temparrLst);

        ArrayList<String> tempArrLstId=setPreParameters(fetchPreDetails, 14);
        System.out.println("VALUE"      +tempArrLstId);
        int length=tempArrLstId.size();

        for(int index=0;index<length;index++)
        {
            System.out.println("VALUE IN KEY"   +  temparrLst.get(index));
            System.out.println("VALUE IN VALUE"   +   tempArrLstId.get(index));
            this.lstBarring.put(temparrLst.get(index), tempArrLstId.get(index));
        }
        System.out.println("INSIDE ODB....>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"   + lstBarring);

    return this.lstBarring;
    }
```

Problem is:

- 1st SOP is KEY-printing all the key correctly.
- 2nd SOP is VALUE-printing all the value correctly.
- 3rd SOP is VALUE IN KEY----printing all the values.
- 4th SOP is VALUE IN VALUE--printing all the values.

Hence after ever iteration I am getting value,value in `HashMap` whereas it should be key,value.

Here's look at my Method:-

```
public ArrayList<String> setPreParameters(HashMap<Integer,String> fetchPreDetails,int index)
    {   
        switch(index)
        {

        case 1:
        {
            arrLstData.clear();
            splittedString=fetchPreDetails.get(1).split(",");
            Collections.addAll(arrLstData, splittedString); 
            break;

        }

return arrLstData;
```

Please guide me as to where am I going wrong.

Comment: I wonder what the second (numeric) parameter in `setPreParameters` does mean? Why is it different (1 vs 14)?

Comment: It's hard to tell just from the code you've given us. If you could produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, that would really help.

Comment: 1 and 14 are the parameters which I am sending to that function to extract values corresponding to those indexes which are getting stored in two arraylist as shown.... ..first output is "david","missu" and second output is "1","2"....

Comment: You can have a look at the yet another code snippet....the actual function call.....

Comment: What are fetchPreDetails, arrLstData, splittedString? Why are you using global variables for these?

Comment: fetchPreDetails is HashMap<Integer,String> which comes from DB...arrLstData is a temp array for this function..I tried putting arraylist inside the function also..Same output..splittedString contains the String[] extracted from fetchPreDetails Hashmap using split method.Since my values are in CSV inside Hashmap, i split it and then used string arrays to convert to ArrayList<String>

Comment: When you say "temp array" I guess you mean that you reuse the exact same array every function call.  That's your bug.  You have to create a new array at each call.  You think you have many arrays, but every array is just a reference to the same object instance.

Comment: @toto2 : in each switch case I am clearing the arraylist and so i Guess my arraylist won't give any trouble...Also function call is returning correct values on both the occassions....sop-1 and sop-2 are giving correct values but after that everything messes up...!If there was aything wrong with the arraylist i guess my sops would have reflected that.....

Comment: Yes, you clear it, but you clear the one and only array in your program and write new values into it.  Both temparrLst and tempArrLstId are pointing to the same space in memory that you keep clearing and writing into.  They need to reference two different ArrayList and the way you do this is by having setPreParameters return a brand new ArrayList each time it's called.  See the answer by Ryan Stewart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that either `fetchPreDetails` is a collection being mutated by `setPreParameters()` or else `setPreParameters()` is mutating some other shared state so that the collection referenced by your `temparrLst` is being changed on the second call to `setPreParameters()`. I.e.

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList();
strings.add("a");
strings.add("b");
List<String> otherStrings = strings;
otherStrings.add("c");
```

I expect your code assumes that `strings` would contain "a" and "b" and that `otherStrings` would contain "a", "b", and "c". This isn't how object references work in Java. The line `List<String> otherStrings = strings;` makes both `strings` and `otherStrings` point to the same collection, and thus changes made using either name affect the same thing.

**Edit:** Your newly-posted code seems to prove my hypothesis. You have a variable called `arrLstData` that you clear, populate, and return on each call to `setPreParameters()`. You're returning the same collection every time you call this method. Therefore you just have multiple handles to the same collection instead of multiple collections. You need to create a new collection and return it each time you call `setPreParameters()`.

**Edit again:** Maybe this will make it clearer. Here's what you're doing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo f = new Foo();
    List<String> list1 = f.getList("a", "b");
    System.out.println(list1);
    List<String> list2 = f.getList("c", "d");
    System.out.println(list2);
    System.out.println(list1);
}

static class Foo {
    private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public List<String> getList(String... strings) {
        myList.clear();
        myList.addAll(Arrays.asList(strings));
        return myList;
    }
}
```

Note that this exhibits exactly the behavior that you're describing, and the correct way to solve it is something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo f = new Foo();
    List<String> list1 = f.getList("a", "b");
    System.out.println(list1);
    List<String> list2 = f.getList("c", "d");
    System.out.println(list2);
    System.out.println(list1);
}

static class Foo {
    public List<String> getList(String... strings) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        result.addAll(Arrays.asList(strings));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Ryan..! setPreParameters() returns an ArrayList<String> on both occassions with different values..I cross checked and that is why 1st SOP and 2nd SOP gives different values...But once the control goes in loop same value is getting stored in key and value...

Comment: Also amazingly if I change the order of two function calls..i see that key gets stored in both key and value pair..... Also fetchPreDetails is actually a HashMap<Integer,String> from which I am extracting CSV values and storing it in ArrayList<String>....Is there any thing wrong with the ArrayList itself.....????

Comment: No....My first List temparrLst contains NAMES...."john","vikam","david" and second List contains VALUES..."1","2","3","4"....Both have no similarity in terms of there contents

Comment: @ankit: Updated my answer. This is very definitely your problem.

Comment: But if that is the problem why is it returning correct output in both the SOP..?????...if I call the same collection again it should give me the previous value along with new value..But then M getting two proper output before the loop...Also once my control comes back to main method I am dealing with loop...I noticed that changing the order of two function call changes the value...key gets stored in both key-value....

Comment: @ankit After your second SOP (print tempArrLstID) redo a `System.out.println("KEY"    +  temparrLst);`.  You'll see how messed up it is.

Comment: @ankit: Updated again. Your problem is a fundamental misunderstanding of how Java object references work. Read and understand the examples I posted.

Comment: @Ryan Stewart that certainly made it crystal clear for me....n now its working....:)...Thanks a ton to everyone....!....@toto2 thanks to u too,.

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the same List over and over at your `setPreParameters` Method.
The List in `arrLstData` is returned and stored in `temparrLst`, now you are clearing the the Lists content, putting new stuff in it and storing it to `tempArrLstId`.
Now the three variables all contain the very same list (they are not equals, its the same!).
There is only one List object at the whole example!

Its like you got a box and label it "A" on one side put stuff in it, label it "B" on another side and wondering why the box "B" is empty when you turn box "A" upside-down.

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe mean something like this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class GlobalsMess {

    private Map<String, String> lstBarring = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private Map<Integer, String> fetchPreDetails = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    public GlobalsMess() {
        fetchPreDetails.put(1, "john,vikam,david");
        fetchPreDetails.put(14, "1,2,3");
    }

    public Map<String, String> getLstBarring() {

        List<String> tempKeys = setPreParameters(fetchPreDetails.get(1));
        System.out.println("KEY" + tempKeys);

        List<String> tempIds = setPreParameters(fetchPreDetails.get(14));
        System.out.println("VALUE" + tempIds);

        for (int index = 0; index < tempIds.size(); index++) {
            System.out.println("VALUE IN KEY" + tempKeys.get(index));
            System.out.println("VALUE IN VALUE" + tempIds.get(index));
            this.lstBarring.put(tempKeys.get(index), tempIds.get(index));
        }
        System.out.println("INSIDE ODB....>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + lstBarring);

        return this.lstBarring;
    }

    public List<String> setPreParameters(String fetchPreDetailsValue) {
        List<String> arrLstData = new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.addAll(arrLstData, fetchPreDetailsValue.split(","));
        return arrLstData;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GlobalsMess().getLstBarring();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
KEY[john, vikam, david]
VALUE[1, 2, 3]
VALUE IN KEYjohn
VALUE IN VALUE1
VALUE IN KEYvikam
VALUE IN VALUE2
VALUE IN KEYdavid
VALUE IN VALUE3
INSIDE ODB....>>>>>>>>>>>>>>{david=3, vikam=2, john=1}
```